# MongoDB aggregatation very slow

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document structure and my aggregation takes forever.
Below is the snippet of my JSON stored in Mongo.

`"project_id" : ObjectId("5c32fa9ffb6fc0600bda7b53"), 
    "campaign_id" : ObjectId("5c5cecd860d3f82c64b1195a"), 
    "respondent_id" : "5c5cecd860d3f82c64b1195b", 
    "status" : "Complete", 
    "demo1Key" : "gender", 
    "demo1Value" : "2", // these values are till 10
    "responses" : [ // this is a dynamic array with the below properties
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c5cecd860d3f82c64b11a54"), 
            "question" : "Question Text ", 
            "answer" : [ // This can be an array or a single text value
                {
                    "id" : 10001, 
                    "option" : "1", 
                    "answer" : "1"
                }
            ]
        }]`

In my nodejs application, I am trying to aggregate my results as stated below.

```
var groupById = { "optionText": "$responses.answer.answer", "question": "$responses.question" };
// create the group by id based on the maximum possible demographics for a single question option.
for (var i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
  groupById[`demo${i}Key`] = `$demo${i}Key`
  groupById[`demo${i}Value`] = `$demo${i}Value`
}
const aggregatorOpts = [
  {
    $match: { 
      $and: [
        {
          "project_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(projId)
        },
        { "status": "Complete" },
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$responses"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$responses.answer"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: groupById,
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  ]

let dbData = await Respondent.aggregate(aggregatorOpts)
```

I have tried to run the profiler and also added some index on the document namely respondent_id, project_id, campaign_id, status

Comment: I find aggregation hard to figure out and after finally managing realised it had changed my 20ms mongoose .populate to about 200ms :/ For me it's the worst thing about mongo

Comment: I have the same problem with aggregation but with running it from Rails. My query works well in the MongoDB shell but it takes a long time in my Rails project. It seems MongoDB driver doesn't use the indexes. Please, let me know if you find the solution.